# Acquired the building name using GPS Coordinates

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-api, google-places-api

I am writing an app to use GPS coordinates obtained by the cell phone itself to retrieve the building name of that location.

For example, if I use this http URL to request with Google Place API:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.805112,-73.960349&radius=10&sensor=false&key="YourKey"

I can only get the **street name** of this coordinate through this.

But if I type "40.805112,-73.960349" in maps.google.com. I can get the exact building name. SO  I was wondering how can I use Google Map API to obtain the building name I want.

Thank you very much about this!!!

Answer (score 0):

The first result in the [request](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.805112,-73.960349&radius=10&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY) you provided contains `"name" : "Church of Notre Dame"`, isn't this what you are looking for?

A better request if you are only interested in the place name at this location would be to use the `rankby=distance` parameter instead or `radius` and to filter by `type=establishment`:

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=40.805112,-73.960349&rankby=distance&types=establishment&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY

This would return the closest place at the given location.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, I might have made a mistake choosing a example. The problem is when I try this coordinates (42.444456,-76.482237) in the same request which was supposed to present "Phillips Hall" in the "name" part, it only returns the road name. But in Google map it can return the correct building name to us.

Comment: I have filed this as a bug internally. Please file it on the [Google Maps Issue Tracker](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug) if you would like to keep track of it.